# has_category() for parent category

Tags: categories, conditional-tags

Is there a way to make a condition for posts belonging to any sub-categories of a given parent category? Here is an example, assuming the following category structure:

- News
- FAQ

  - 1) Installing
  - 2) Using, etc.
- Other

```
if ( has_category( 'FAQ' ) ) { 
    echo "This page has been updated for Quick Access Popup v10.";
}
else {
    echo "This page has NOT been updated for Quick Access Popup v10 yet.";
}
```

The has_category() condition includes only posts that are in the category 'FAQ' itself, but not those in its subcategories. I know I could use an array and list every categories but this is not convenient and need to be maintained when subcategories are added, removed, etc.

The has_category() doc says nothing about parent categories (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/)

Thanks.

Comment: try this function and test the parent : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

Comment: @Kaperto can you write an answer? It'll only work in term archives though

Comment: And only for one level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you'll need to get a list of all the child categories of the category you want, and then check those. But you don't need to write that list manually. You can use `get_term_children()` to get the IDs of the child and grandchild categories:

```
$cat_id   = get_cat_ID( 'FAQ' );
$children = get_term_children( $cat_id, 'category' );

if ( has_category( $cat_id ) || has_category( $children ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob Peattie. This is exactly what I needed. I changed it a bit because I want the snippet to be displayed only in the post of the children categories but also in the children categories pages themselves: if `( is_category( $children ) || has_category( $children ) ) { ... }`

Comment: You can just remove `is_category( $children ) ||`  if you want to do that.